# JSON::RPC::Client installation in windows

Tags: windows, perl

I want to run a [`JSON::RPC::Client`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-RPC-0.96/lib/JSON/RPC/Client.pm) to run my perl script in windows 7.
Can you guys help me where I can find the installation or the library

Thanks
Rikky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of `JSON::RPC`.

For ActiveState Perl: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/JSON-RPC/

On Strawberry Perl you should just be able to install it using the cpan client.